# Retrieve an array of next/previous most recent files

Tags: python, linux, filter, filesystems

See following code. When I call `get_files_by_most_recent` I get the most recent files with a threshold of 1 second.

```
import os
class FileSystem:
    @staticmethod
    def get_files_by_most_recent(directory, threshold=1.0):
        files = FileSystem.get_files(directory)
        files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(directory, x)))
        filtered = filter(lambda y: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(directory, files[-1])) - os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(directory, y)) <= threshold, files)
        return filtered

    @staticmethod
    def get_files(directory):
        files = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, f))]
        return files
```

Now I'd like two new methods:

- one for stepping forward - to next most recent set of files
- one for stepping backwards - to previous most recent set of files, a.k.a. reverse

How would I do that?

Here is a sample file list:

```
sceflh.jpg - 2014-08-23 05:07:46.100000000
rgxanx.jpg - 2014-08-23 05:07:45.900000000
byoiup.jpg - 2014-08-23 05:07:45.700000000
rrqgnh.jpg - 2014-08-23 05:07:45.500000000
sqthcv.jpg - 2014-08-23 05:07:40.320000000
ebrmvv.jpg - 2014-08-23 05:07:40.200000000
xzvsnt.jpg - 2014-08-24 08:12:01.110000000
ckiinz.jpg - 2014-08-24 08:12:01.100000000
```

Comment: if you want the next would it  not be the time at which you requested the current +1 second and the reverse for previous?

Comment: Not sure where I would apply current+1. Also wouldn't current+1 just give me the next file - rather than the next set of files?

Comment: I meant to run the code again basing   the threshold on the time of when you got your current set of files, basically store the time and work off that

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks, will try to work something out.